# Como configurar um driver para uma conexão remota em Java?

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, oracle, netbeans

Estou tentando conectar remotamente através dos dados:

```
URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@grad.icmc.usp.br:15215:orcl";
    usuario = "usr";
    senha = "usr";
    ORACLEDRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; // <---
```

De modo que tento fazer a conexão:

```
try {
             //Definindo que o JDBC saiba que é o driver da Oracle que deve ser usado na conexão!
            Class.forName(ORACLEDRIVER);
             System.out.println("Configuração do Driver Oracle bem-sucedida");
            
        
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, usuario, senha);
            System.out.println("Conexão bem-sucedida");

            //se o driver der problema...
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {
                  System.out.println("Class not found");  // <--           
        }
```

Sempre estou caindo na mensagem de erro `class not found` justamente porque o driver não foi corretamente configurado.

Tentei usar um código para configurar algum outro driver corretamente, que foi: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`, e como a tentativa é bem sucedida, ele apresenta a mensagem de que o driver foi configurado, porém, como esse não é o driver correto, ele apresenta em sequência que esse não é o driver correto.

Portanto tenho certeza de que o erro está justamente no link para especificar o driver da oracle. Como posso descobrir qual é o link correto do driver?

Ao configurar manualmente o bd via netbeans, é solicidado um driver `ojdbc7.jar`, e eu baixei e adicionei ele. Mas na hora de conectar via minha aplicação está dando esse erro do `class not found`.

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido!

A sentença `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` está correta, porém o `ojdbc7.jar` que já tinha sido configurado no menu "services" do netbeans não foi o suficiente para configurar o driver.

Foi necessário adicionar o `.jar` na pasta `Dependences > add dependency > ojdbc7 > ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar` . Após isso ele acusa que não foi feito o download corretamente, e se for o caso basta ir com botão direito: `Manually install artifact >  ojdbc7.jar` e assim ele vai funcionar.